# What are the neurological similarities between humans and primates?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, anthropology

I don't know exactly what primate specie is considered to be out ancestor. But the next question regards them.

Assuming that in the beginning *we considered true the remnants of many trial & error tests, the question is straightforward:

Do we have some specific neural processes similar to primates - for example those involving:

- Simple comparisons*,
- analogies**
- you may add another?

Can we go even deeper in the animal's kingdom and find those similarities? How deep?

Any research study (paper) or essay is welcomed. I don't pretend a complete answer but some guidelines.

---

<sup>* like "what is bigger A or B?"

** like "if A is like they maybe B too".</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primate brains are considered to be highly similar to ours. In terms of their structure, it's more appropriate to look for the differences than the similarities.

However, you're asking for [cognitive skills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_skill) and these are mediated by cortical structures, and especially the higher association areas. This is exactly where the similarities are starting to break down, as the cortex, and hence [higher order processing has rapidly expanded](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-has-human-brain-evolved/) in human evolution. Notably, the surface area of the cortex has greatly expanded in humanoids through a progressive increase in the number of gyri and sulci ('wrinkles') in the cortical surface. A greater cortical surface correlates with higher cognitive abilities in humans (Fig. 1). This is what sets us apart. [**Cognition**](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/primate-cognition-59751723) being

> [T]he ability to interpret and connect information that is perceived in the world and to then apply this personal knowledge adaptively to future situations and problems.

While humanoids have exceptionally well-developed cognitive skills, non-humanoid primates do have been shown to exhibit quite sophisticated cognitive capabilities as well. In a review article, [Hopper & Brosnan (2012)](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/primate-cognition-59751723) state that primates have been shown to:

- Recall serial lists of images
- Select purpose-specific tools and save them for later
- Manufacture purpose-specific tools, demonstrating an understanding of causal relations and physical properties
- Have intricate social interactions and are known to interact with and manipulate other group members

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Hopper & Brosnan. Nature Education Knowledge (2012); **5**(8): 3](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/primate-cognition-59751723)</sub>

[image: human vs chimp brain]
<sup>Fig. 1. human brain (top) and chimp brains (bottom) are very similar. Especially the cortex is larger in humans. source: [Tes Teach - Brain Project](https://www.tes.com/lessons/WmxSHY-4aykCfA/brain-inquiry-project)</sup>